# Position fixed element outside of <body> is inserted inside of <body>

Tags: html, css

When I put an element like `<div>` outside of  element, which is set as "position: fixed", it appears inside of `<body>`.

I'm told that the "position: fixed" makes its element put into `<body>` even if it's outside of it.

Is that correct? and what's good and bad when do code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't allow a `<div>` element to appear outside the `<body>` element.

HTML's parsing rules (and error recovery) will move the element back inside the `<body>`.

CSS has nothing to do with it.

Follow the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). Write [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Is that so, what the guy told is absolutely wrong. right? that means that Some browser has no such parsing and recovery feature will occurs error or ignore the div element outside of body element.

Comment: If you look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html), the only permitted child elements of `<html>` are a single `<head>` element followed by a single `<body>` element.